# align columns of divs with fluid layout in bootstrap 2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a simple two-column fluid layout using `Bootstrap 2`. One column contains two `div`, and the other contains three `div`. Both columns are of `span6`. The fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6xr6X/1/).

I attempted to adjust the heights of the two `div`s in the left column using CSS, so that the top one occupies 62.5% of the browser window height, while the bottom one occupies the rest 37.5%. And similarly for the three `div`s in the right column. But there are a few questions/problems:

1. The heights of the blocks/`div`s do not fill up the window vertically, and the height of each block/`div` is not changed.
2. How to make the total height of the two `div`s on the left equal to that of the three `div`s on the right, while respecting the relative height ratio within each column (`left: 62.5%, 37.5%; right: 35%, 30%, 35%`)
3. How to adjust the paddings between blocks/`div`s?

I hope all of these can be achieved without any Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried something, I hope that helps you. So, answers are:

1. Height of each BlocX div is not changed because you didn't set height of `body`. In tour case, body have auto height, given by elements inside of `body`.
2. Look below.
3. Those "paddings" are actually margins in class `.well`. So, avoid that class or override settings.

Finally, we have code like this:

HTML:

Removed class `.well`, everything else is the same.

CSS:

```
html{height:100%;}

.body-background {
    padding-top: 10px;
    background-color: #D1D1D1;
    height:100%;
}
.container-fluid, .row-fluid, .span6
{
    height:100%;
}

#A-b {
    min-height: 62.5%;
    height: 62.5%;
    background-color: #FFE0C2;
}

#B-b {
    min-height: 37.5%;
    height: 37.5%;
    background-color: #4D4D4D;
}

#C-b {
    min-height: 35%;
    height: 35%;
    background-color: #969696;
}

#D-b {
    min-height: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    background-color: #57BCFF;
}

#E-b {
    min-height: 35%;
    height: 35%;
    background-color: #183547;
}
```

We give to `html` and `body` elements `height:100%;` and after that do the same to `.container-fluid`, `.row-fluid` and `.span6`. Now we have result like this in [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6xr6X/3/).

NOTE: In resolutions smaller than 768px, use media queries to set height of BlockX and all other elements. Also, don't set height directly on `span6`, `row-fluid` etc. This is just example. In live site, use some classes to override classes in bootstrap.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I would like to keep using `well` class from Bootstrap, which however will result in the vertical gaps between `div`s within the same `span6` element. In addition, how can we adjust the horizontal gap between the two `span6` `divs`?

Comment: you're right! So how can we make the two columns the same total height without dropping the `well` class?